# Can't Get-ACL Active Directory OU

Tags: powershell, active-directory, acl

I need to delegate rights (read, write, create child object, etc.) on AD OU for a service account.

I used the following code found [here](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/ou-permission-delegation-using-powershell/).

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$rootdse = Get-ADRootDSE

$guidmap = @{}
Get-ADObject -SearchBase ($rootdse.SchemaNamingContext) -LDAPFilter `
"(schemaidguid=*)" -Properties lDAPDisplayName,schemaIDGUID |
% {$guidmap[$_.lDAPDisplayName]=[System.GUID]$_.schemaIDGUID}

$extendedrightsmap = @{}
Get-ADObject -SearchBase ($rootdse.ConfigurationNamingContext) -LDAPFilter `
"(&amp;(objectclass=controlAccessRight)(rightsguid=*))" -Properties displayName,rightsGuid |
% {$extendedrightsmap[$_.displayName]=[System.GUID]$_.rightsGuid}

$domain = Get-ADDomain
```

## MyOU is like "OU=xxx - [xx],OU=XXXXX,OU=XXX,DC=AD,DC=GROUPE,DC=NET"

```
$OU = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Identity 'MyOU'

$p = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier (Get-ADuser "testaccount").SID
$acl = Get-ACL $ou.DistinguishedName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Access

$acl.AddAccessRule((New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule `
$p,"WriteProperty","Allow","Descendents",$guidmap["user"]))

Set-ACL -ACLObject $acl -Path ("AD:\"+($ou.DistinguishedName))
```

I'm stuck with the get-ACL command which returns that the path in my AD does not exist, but it does.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting the ACL using:

```
Set-ACL -ACLObject $acl -Path ("AD:\"+($ou.DistinguishedName))
```

Why not getting it get same way?

```
Get-ACL -Path ("AD:\"+($ou.DistinguishedName))
```

Or like that:

```
Get-ACL -Path "AD:\$($ou.DistinguishedName)"
```

Comment: @vegeta You must use the `AD:` drive for `Get-Acl` to work. If that produced an empty result you need to dig further into that. What was the exact statement you ran? What were your input values? Were there any errors? Please edit your question to provide this information.

Comment: I think I found why the get-acl return nothing. In the name of my OU given in input, I have the caracters [ and ]  "OU=test dsi - [12345].....".  It seems that the command don't like it. I try on an OU without these caracteres and the command works.

Comment: Try it again with `Get-Acl -LiteralPath` instead of `Get-Acl -Path`. Does this work for you?

Comment: Same erreur with the literalPath : Unable to find the acces path  " //RootDSE/OU=...." because it does not exist

Comment: so finally I decide to use dsacls. I did not manage to use the get-acl on OU that contains brackets in name. thanks

Answer (score 1):

PS is really annoying at times... try this:

set-location ad:    #This makes the following command work!!!!

Get-ACL -Path ("AD:"+($ou.DistinguishedName))

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert to HEX format the values which `Get-Acl` CmdLet doesn't like.

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>$a = "[]"
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>$c=""
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Foreach ($element in $a.ToCharArray()) {$c = $c + "\" + [System.String]::Format("{0:X2}", [System.Convert]::ToUInt32($element))}
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>$c
\5B\5D
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>
```

So you need to pass `"OU=test dsi - \5B12345\5D....."` to `Get-Acl` instead of `OU=test dsi - [12345]`, e.g.

```
> Get-Acl -Path "AD:OU=test dsi - \5B12345\5D,DC=ad,DC=local"
```

Also you can convert the whole OU name (not including `OU=` part):

```
> Get-Acl -Path "AD:OU=\74\65\73\74\20\64\73\69\20\2D\20\5B\31\32\33\34\35\5D,DC=ad,DC=local"
```

Answer (score 0):

The other comments here saying you must prefix the OU with "AD:" when doing Get-Acl are correct. I ran into an issue where you sometimes get an error:

```
get-acl : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'AD' does not exist.
```

But why wouldn't the AD: drive be mapped? I found if you use another function that looks up something in AD, the drive gets mapped. If you first run something like this:

```
Get-ADGroup "Domain Admins"
```

and then run your Get-Acl command, Get-Acl will succeed at finding the 'AD' drive.